# Need a RegEx to match subject in bounced email header

Tags: regex, newline

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match the subject of a bounced email by looking in the header. I need to extract "Membership Activation" from this email header:

```
Received: from DOMAIN.mydomain.com (UnknownHost [127.0.0.1]) by DOMAIN.mydomain.net with SMTP;
   Fri, 6 Sep 2013 10:34:07 -0600
Date: Fri, 6 Sep 2013 10:34:07 -0600 (MDT)
From: "MyDomain.com" 
To: test@anotherdomain.com
Message-ID: <8279725.100.1378485247161.JavaMail.MYDOMAIN$@127.0.0.1>
Subject: Membership Activation
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

I tried:

```
^Subject: (.+)$
```

But ^ and $ don't work because these are CRLFs. Then I tried:

```
[\r\n]+Subject: ((.[^\r\n])+)
```

But I'm not getting the last "n" of "Membership Activation" in group 2 of the result. I'm not sure if my negation of the CRLF is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Be aware that subject lines, especially UTF-8 ones, often wrap onto newlines. Depending on your environment you should probably find a dedicated email parsing library to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine, the problem is that the start-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$` anchors match only at the beginning and end of entire string by default.

This can be fixed easily by using a special modifier in your regular expression definition that makes `^` and `$` match at the start and end of each line instead of start and end of entire string or input. This modifier is language or tool dependent so you have to look up the documentation of the tool or language you are using to figure out what is the modifier.

For example in PHP:

```
/^Subject: (.+)$/im
                  ^
     Notice the m modifier which makes ^ and $ match at the start and end of each line
```

in Perl, the same as PHP:

```
/^Subject: (.+)$/im
```

In Javascript, the same as PHP:

```
/^Subject: (.+)$/im
```

In Python pass the following string to the regex constructor or a method that accepts a regular expression string:

```
r"(?m)^Subject: (.+)$"
```

In Java, the same as Python:

```
"(?m)^Subject: (.+)$"
```

In .NET, for every method that deals with regular expressions, there is an overload which accepts a `RegexOptions` enumeration that turn multi-line mode on:

```
RegexOptions.Mutliline
```

[Regex101 Demo in PHP](http://regex101.com/r/zY6zS0)

**Edit:** Apparently you are using ColdFusion so if all of the above doesn't work with you then try the following expression:

```
[\s\S]+Subject: (.+)
```

but it is not as efficient as the previous options.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qW4lO2)

Comment: Hmmm... I'll look into how I might do this with ColdFusion, but I'm not sure I can.

Comment: @Redtopia I think ColdFusion uses Java underneath so try the Java syntax.

Comment: @Redtopia I have edited my answer to give you another alternative, please check edit.

Comment: In CF, you precede the RegEx with (?m), so my RegEx was "(?m)^Subject: (.*?)$". I had to trim the result because it included the CRLF at the end. I could also use native Java, but I think I've got it working with the Trim().

Answer (score 1):

Try: `[\r\n]+Subject: (([^\r\n])+)`

I'm getting the last 'n' with that.

Comment: I'm using ColdFusion, which for some reason is not matching the last n. I did not including the entire, exact header, which might be why your test worked.

Comment: I'm using Reggy on the Mac and also get a missing 'n' using your original pattern.